# how to check the last_modified date with null values in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table called orders in which data is loaded through a CSV file into a loader table for every three hours. I have a column last_modified set to `SYSDATE` which records the insert and update on the table. Recently, I have observed that the last_modified column has null values for more than 100k records when update happens. Is there any way to fix this issue?

```
Merge into orders d
  using (select * from ods_prm_data ) s
    on (d.order_id = s.order_id)
  when not matched then
    insert (d.order_id ,d.ID, d.last_modified)
    values (s.order_id, s.ID,s.order_seq.val,SYSDATE)
  when matched then
    update set d.last_modified = SYSDATE;
```

Comment: [`CREATE TRIGGER ... BEFORE INSERT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm#i2153487) ?

Comment: That being said, this is not a normal behavior you describe. Maybe the right question to ask is _"what's wrong with my import procedure ?"_

Comment: It's a simple merge statement where last_update is happening on and off.. there are no triggers enabled on this table..the last_updated date has values for a few records and a few records fail to update due to which I am unable to distinguish when the record is inserted or updated..

Comment: I can see that this trigger can be used for future purpose, but for the old set of records .. how can I check when they are inserted or updated on the target table?

Comment: It seems likely that either A) the MERGE statement is not setting LAST_UPDATED in some case, or B) LAST_UPDATED is being cleared after having been set correctly. I doubt that anyone here can explain what's going on, but if you edit your question and include the MERGE statement and any other relevant logic we can at least have a look. Best of luck.

Comment: MERGE INTO orders d  USING (SELECT b.order_id,                               b.order_type, b.order_version,
                    b.order_date ord_date, b.crd crd, b.ccd ccd, b.idd idd,
                    b.SYSTEM, b.order_manager, b.customer_id, b.customer_name,
                    b.service_name, b.sales_channel, b.sales_channel_type,
                    b.customer_signed_date, b.delay_reason, b.delay_type,

Comment: Merge into orders d using (select * from ods_prm_data ) s    on (d.order_id = s.order_id) when not matched then insert (d.order_id ,d.ID, d.last_modified) values (s.order_id, s.ID,s.order_seq.val,SYSDATE) when matched then update set d.last_modified = SYSDATE;

Comment: Just a note: don't put clarifying information into comments. Edit the question (you can always edit your own questions) and include the clarifying information in the question itself. Thanks.

Comment: The first merge statement you put into a comment above is incomplete. Please edit the question and include both insert statements (I put the one from the second comment into the question already).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `WHEN NOT MATCHED` branch of the MERGE statement. I'm rather surprised that this statement even compiled because the INSERT field list `(d.order_id ,d.ID, d.last_modified)` specifies three fields, but the VALUES list `(s.order_id, s.ID,s.order_seq.val, SYSDATE)`shows FOUR values. I'm not sure how this slipped past the compiler, and I have no idea how it's being executed; however, it may help to explain the issues you're having.

Best of luck.